# Run another AsyncTask in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What if I need to run another async task being in another async task, meaning in `onPostExecute()` method, how to do so?

Comment: Why do you assume it's not possible to fire up an AsyncTask in `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Who stop you doing that..?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a recommendation, try to off-load as many time's taking calls in your first `AsyncTask` as you can. However, if your application design is in such a way that you only need to execute another task once the first task is completed then simply execute the second `AsyncTask` exactly in the same way as you are doing for the first one.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     new MySecondAsyncTask().execute(params);   //params if any
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code to create a `NewAsyncTask` in `onPostExecute` and then execute the new task.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    NewAsyncTask newtask = new NewAsyncTask();
    newtask.execute();    
}
```