# Android - Run asynchronous task in AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

What is the proper way of calling asynchronous task in a method that may be running in `AsyncTask`?

Documentation states that `execute()` method of `AsyncTask` has to be run on UI thread, so I cannot just run another `AsyncTask` in `AsyncTask`...

Comment: onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result result) is running on UI thread. So you can continue calling another AsyncTask after or before your running current task. Just like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146825/run-another-asynctask-in-onpostexecute). Or you may try to wrap the call using  "runOnUiThread" inside doInBackground().

Answer (score 0):

Any of these will do:
* Run from `onPostExecute(), onPreExecute()` which run on the UI thread.
* Run from `doInBackground()` with the following code

```
runOnUiThread {
@Override
  public void run() {
  // ... your code here.
}
```