# Multiple Async Task in one Activity of Android Apps

Tags: android

Get data from 3 different rest calls in a single activity. . The data from the first asyntask will be used to fire the next two async task.  How can I do this using asynctasks

Comment: Fire AsyncTask 2 from `onPostExecute` of AsyncTask 1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16146872/833647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ken Wolf for the am

```
`@Override
```

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     new MySecondAsyncTask().execute(params);   //params if any
}`